# Lambda OrderBy method

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I have a graphing class to detect circular dependencies in some business logic I am writing. My graphing class builds nodes that knows the relationship to other nodes.

I have nodeList as List(of Objects) each having a List(of String)

I was thinking that the below line of code would yield the correct sorting. I thought wrong.

```
nodeList.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Count)
```

I want to reorder my nodeList in descending order by the List(of String).Count.

```
my List(of Object)
(0) | Count = 3
(1) | Count = 5
(2) | Count = 2

My desired output List(of Object)
(0) | Count = 5
(1) | Count = 3
(2) | Count = 2
```

Comment: Looks like it's sorted descending to me.  What's the issue?

Comment: That is my desired output from the reorder

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`OrderByDescending` does not reorder the list in-place.  It *returns* an enumerator that you can use to get a new ordered list.  You need to use `.ToList()` to replace the original list:

```
 nodeList = nodeList.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Count).ToList()
```

Comment: This assumes that each node has a Count property that returns the Count of the contained string list. Something like `x.MyStringList.Count` might be worth mentioning.